# Wrong arrangement leads to wrong answer

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

10 ambassadors are being arranged uniformly at random in a row. What is the
probability that: The French ambassador is next to the Russian ambassador?

The answer in the textbook is :  "By viewing
the two ambassadors as one, we infer that there are exactly 2! · 9! possibilities in which the
French ambassador is next to the Russian ambassador" Answer is : $\frac{2!\cdot 9!}{10!}$.
I don't understand why it is written there 9 instead of 8. because we have 2 taken seats, and left with 8 that can be arranged(8!)

Comment: There's a Saying in computer science: Garbage in , garbage out -GIGO. I would say, make a pack of the two, so they're always together then subtract from the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative method which uses $8!$:

- There are $9$ adjacent pairs of seats to place these two ambassadors: $1\&2, 2\&3, 3\&4,\ldots,9 \&10$
- These two ambassadors can be seated $2!$ ways in the selected pair of seats
- The other eight ambassadors can be seated $8!$ ways in the remaining seats
- Divide by $10!$ to reflect the number of originally equally likely possibilities

and that gives a result of $\frac{9\cdot 2!\cdot8!}{10!}= \frac15$ as before

Comment: Thank you! this way speaks more sense to me for some reason. I've seen that there are 9 sub groups of adjacent seats. I did draw it on board and that there is 9. Do you maybe know the formula for such case? because thre might be a bigger number(more than 10)?

Comment: With $n$ ambassadors of which $k$ must sit together, you get $\dfrac{(n-k+1)k!(n-k)!}{n!}=\dfrac{k!(n-k+1)!}{n!}$

Answer (score 2):

The method the solution has used is to treat the French and Russian ambassador as one, so that is now 8 ambassadors plus "one" ambassador which is the French and Russian ambassador combined, so there are 9 ambassadors. There are $2!$ ways to arrange just the French and Russian ambassador and "nine" ambassadors. So there are $2!9!$ ways for the French Ambassador and Russian ambassador to be sitting next to each other. Then divide that result by $10!$, the total number of different seating arrangements for the ten ambassadors.